# How to exclude lower bound when using random.uniform?

Tags: python

The documentation of this function indicates it includes low, but excludes high.

```
import random

random.uniform(low, high)
```

Is there a way to exclude low as well?

It should be noted that high could possibly be very close to low.

Comment: What do you expect the outcome to be when both high and low are excluded?

Comment: But yes, it is possible to apply the function as `random.uniform()`. The result is a drawn from a uniform distribution from 0 to 1. If you do `random.uniform(high = 5)`, then you draw from a uniform distribution from 0 to 5.

Comment: You can simply redraw if you get the low value until you get a value larger than the low value.

Answer (score -1):

Is this a valid answer?

```
import random
import sys

low = sys.float_info.epsilon
random.uniform(low, high)
```